# Android: Custom GridView issue at item position 0

Tags: android, gridview

I've been sitting on this problem for a whole day now and still can't solve it. I hope you can help. I have a custom GridView, it has issues when loading an image on item position 0:

1. It gets called 3 times everytime.
2. The image isn't shown BEFORE I take some actions(let's say I click a button to navigate to another page and go back to that page. Now I can see the image).

I am using this CustomGridView: [ExpandableHeightGridView](https://gist.github.com/sakurabird/6868765)

My adapter:

```
private final class SubCatListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    public JSONArray data;
    private final Context context;

    public SubCatListAdapter(Context context, JSONArray values) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.data = values;
    }

    // ...

    class ViewHolder {

        public TextView txtViewCatName;
        public SimpleDraweeView imgLogo;

    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder viewHolder = null;

        if (rowView == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gamification_subcat_adapter, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.imgLogo = (SimpleDraweeView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
            viewHolder.txtViewCatName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewCatName);

            rowView.setTag(viewHolder);

        } else {

            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        // data
        try {
            JSONObject node = getItem(position);
            viewHolder.txtViewCatName.setText(Html.fromHtml(node.getString("CatName")).toString());
            String catLogo = node.getString("CatLogoPath");
            viewHolder.imgLogo.setImageURI(Uri.parse(catLogo));
            Log.d("TAG", "position: " + position);

            return rowView;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new View(context);
        }
    }

}
```

Log.d tag shows that position 0 is loaded 3 times:

```
D/TAG﹕ position: 0
D/TAG﹕ position: 0
D/TAG﹕ position: 0
D/TAG﹕ position: 1
D/TAG﹕ position: 2
D/TAG﹕ position: 3
```

Here is my item at position 0,1,2,3 :

[image]

Please help~~I'm dying...Thanks in advanced!

Comment: please check your jsonarray before setting adapter to grid

Comment: Hi @user3676184 , thanks for your suggestion, may I know further what kind of checking do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private final class SubCatListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

public JSONArray data;
private final Context context;

public SubCatListAdapter(Context context, JSONArray values) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.data = values;
}

// ...

class ViewHolder {

    public TextView txtViewCatName;
    public SimpleDraweeView imgLogo;

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rowView = convertView;
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();



        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gamification_subcat_adapter, parent, false);

        viewHolder.imgLogo = (SimpleDraweeView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgLogo);
        viewHolder.txtViewCatName = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewCatName);

        rowView.setTag(viewHolder);



    // data
    try {
        JSONObject node = getItem(position);
        viewHolder.txtViewCatName.setText(Html.fromHtml(node.getString("CatName")).toString());
        String catLogo = node.getString("CatLogoPath");
        viewHolder.imgLogo.setImageURI(Uri.parse(catLogo));
        Log.d("TAG", "position: " + position);

        return rowView;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new View(context);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Awesome! It still loads the first item 3 times but it solved my second mentioned issue which is the main concern. I removed the 'if (rowView == null){}' checking as your provided answer and it works. But I don't get it, I saw most of the online samples of custom listView/gridView are with the checking, why will it affect my first item in gridview?